# How to reshape a whole batch in Keras model?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to reshape a whole batch in Keras so that it will transform from (?, 28, 28, 1) to (?/10, 10, 28, 28, 1). Is it possible to implement with Keras?

I have a dataset where labels are per group of images (let's call it 'bag') but not per images themselves. I'd like to load images from folder using Keras `ImageDataGenerator` and its `flow_from_directory()` method and then reshape images inside the model itself.

```py
from keras.datasets import mnist
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Lambda

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

def test_model(data):
    from keras import Model
    from keras.models import Input
    input_layer = Input(shape=data.shape[1:])
    layer = Lambda(lambda x: K.reshape(x,
                                       (-1, 10, *data.shape[1:])),
                   output_shape=(-1, 10, *data.shape[1:]))(input_layer)
    model = Model(inputs=[input_layer], outputs=[layer])
    model.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='mean_squared_error')
    return model.predict(data, batch_size=60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_model(x_train)
```

I expected the model to reshape each batch and return it somehow (to be honest, I don't know how Keras concatenates results of each batch when predicting).
Instead of results, I get error:

`ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (6,10,28,28) into shape (60,10,28,28)`

Comment: Why would you want to do something like this?

Comment: Remove the `output_shape` parameter. It's unnecessary and it's wrong too (no batch dimension required there, so no `-1`)

Comment: It turned out that it is impossible to split into different 'bags' this way because we cannot process y_labels in any layer. I'll go and try another approach of preprocessing. Thanks everyone for you comments!